# I have an issue with my code in regard to returning a solution from my user input code and "str" not callable. Trying to add together display results

Tags: python

I am trying to add together two user inputs for numbers and show the results of the two added together.
This is what my code currently looks like:

```py
number1= eval(input("total price of cleaning for your house size:"))

number2= eval(input("Price for the cleaning type:"))

def addition(a,b): 
    addition =a-b

    return addition 

print("You owe:",addition(int(number1),int(number2)))
```

both user inputs are based on earlier calculations within my code.
I had submitted a code almost identical to this, and it had performed correctly, so I am not sure why this one is not.

**In the "assistant" it shows "str" is not callable, and redefining the name "addition" from the outer scope.**

I have tried multiple different ways to make this code work and have not been able to have it run successfully to where it calculates and displays the cost.

Comment: looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) eval doesn't seem to automatically pick up you global and local variables, you need to pass them into the eval function as a dictionary.

Comment: Weird to name a function addition and to a minus, but whatever.  I tried your code and it works fine.  Maybe change the variable name in your addition function to something else.  Name the variable "returnvalue" or something.  FYI using `int` will remove the cents.  This code will only work with full amounts.

Comment: You do not need the `eval`, it works without it.

Comment: Although the code is rather odd  (including using eval), as has been already commented, it does work as written. So it would be useful if you provided the stack trace which accompanied the error indication. The problems would seem to arise elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

eval return int try this :

```
number1= eval(input("total price of cleaning for your house size:"))

number2= eval(input("Price for the cleaning type:"))

def addition(a,b): 
addition =a-b

return addition



print("You owe:",addition(number1,number2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Ive been so frustrated with this so I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @Meghan Has this answered your question? If so, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't want to use eval, just:

```
number1= input("total price of cleaning for your house size:")

number2= input("Price for the cleaning type:")

def addition(a,b): 
    addition =a-b

    return addition 

print("You owe:",addition(int(number1),int(number2)))
```

[input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) will present a prompt and read the value entered by the user into a string. [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) will parse the expression the user enters and will try to execute it as a python script; the return value will be the results of evaluating the text as a python script. So, for example, `x = 1; eval("x+1")` will return 2.

I assume you just want to read an integer value, so:

```
number = int(input("Price for the cleaning type:"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Ive been very frustrated with this and im so glad I have a direction!!